# Java design question: Is this a good design?

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns

I am writing a Java client that communicates with a remote server via HTTP/XML.

Server sends commands to my client in XML format, like this:

```
<command>
<name>C1</name>
<param>
.....
</param>
</command>
```

There is about 10 or more different commands (C1, C2, ...), each of them has different set of params.

My client will process the command, then response server with a execute result, looks like this:

```
<C1>
<code>200</code>
<desc>xxx</desc>
</C1>
```

I am only familiar with C, but very new to Java and OOP,

so, my question is simple, how to design the following logic gracefully in a OOP way?

1.Convert the XML string to an XML Object
2.Find correspoding executor based on 'name' element of the XML, and parse the params
3.Execute the command along with the params
4.Convert the result to an XML Object
5.Convert the XML Object to an XML string

Is this a good design?

1.Define an abstract base class and many sub-classes for each command, which include the following method:

```
void parseCommand(MyXMLObject obj);
void execute();
MyXMLObject generateResult();
```

or just a simple method:

```
MyXMLObject execute(MyXMLObject obj);
```

and these fields:

```
String mCommandName;
int mRetCode;
String mRetDesc;
```

2.Then define a factory class to return an instance of one of the sub-classes based on the XML Object.

3.The logic part code:

```
MyXMLObject obj = MyXMLUtil.getXMLObject(XMLString);
MyCommand command = MyCommandFactory.getCommand(obj);
MyXMLObject retObj = command.execute();
String retStr = MyXMLUtil.getString(retObj);
...//network operation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is a good design (you probably need more interfaces and such, and there are various refinements).

The greater problem is that this is, in many ways, a reinvention of the wheel. There are numerous frameworks that handle mapping from POJOs (java objects) to structured textual formats (such as XML or JSON). On top of that, there are many general implementations of command frameworks. It might be worth investigating available options before you provide your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have been looking for some 'command frameworks', but haven't found any good examples yet :(

Comment: @bhh: Almost every company that I've been to has a very nice and tested implementation of the command patter. I'm sure there are also open source alternatives (though this might deserve a separate stackoverflow question). But there are definitely off-the-shelf solutions for going from POJOs to a format like XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes, that's how things work. But I think you should separate the different concerns.

Basically I'd say you have a service layer that needs to execute commands and return the results. This layer should know nothing about XML, so I'd design the plain Java Object model and then worry about tying it to your XML infrastructure, probably using an existing XML mapping technology like XStream.

Comment: JAXB is the standard (JSR-222) for object-to-XML mapping:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html.  XStream is a serialization technology:  http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Uses

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, the design looks pretty good. To make your life easier, you should have a look at [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to parse XML -> Java and to create XML from Java objects.

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html

Comment: @Blaise: +1. I'm usually suspicious about Java standards but since you compare Simple and JAXB side by side, I'll try it for my next project.